# Find and print vowels from a string using a while loop

Tags: python-3.x

**Study assignment (using python 3):**

For a study assignment I need to write a program that prints the indices of all vowels in a string, preferably using a 'while-loop'.
So far I have managed to design a 'for-loop' to get the job done, but I could surely need some help on the 'while-loop'

**for-loop solution:**

```
string = input( "Typ in a string: " )
vowels = "a", "e", "i", "o", "u"
indices = ""

for i in string:
    if i in vowels:
        indices += i
print( indices )
```

**while-loop solution:**

```
string = input( "Typ in a string: " )
vowels = "a", "e", "i", "o", "u"
indices = ""

while i < len( string ):
    <code>
    i += 1
print( indices )
```

Would the use **'index()'** or **'find()'** work here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the character at index x of a string by doing `string[x]`!

```
i = 0 # initialise i to 0 here first!
while i < len( string ):
    if string[i] in vowels:
        indices += str(i)
    i += 1
print( indices )
```

However, is making `indices` a `str` really suitable? I don't think so, since you don't have separators between the indices. Is the string `"12"` mean that there are 2 vowels at index 1 and 2, or one vowel index 12? You can try using a list to store the indices:

```
indices = []
```

And you can add `i` to it by doing:

```
indices.append(i)
```

BTW, your for loop solution will print the vowel characters, not the indices.

If you don't want to use lists, you can also add an extra space after each index.

```
indices += str(I) + " "
```

Comment: Thank you Sweeper! The difficulty is that I haven't learned to work with lists yet, next two chapters are tuples & lists. I really still struggle to be creative using only the 'tools' we learned so far (these include: expressions, variables, conditions, iterations, functions, and the current chapter 'strings') But I do understand your explanation, thank you for your help!

Comment: @GJ01 I edited the answer. There *is* a way around this.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much! :-) And you are right with the 'vowels' and 'indices' too, but I didn't have a clue how to return the indices.

Answer (score 1):

> Try This :

```
   string = input( "Typ in a string: " )
    vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]




        higher_bound=1
        lower_bound=0

        while lower_bound<higher_bound:
            convert_str=list(string)
            find_vowel=list(set(vowels).intersection(convert_str))
            print("Vowels in {} are {}".format(string,"".join(find_vowel)))

            lower_bound+=1
```

You can also set higher_bound to len(string) then it will print result as many times as len of string.

Since this is your Study assignment you should look and practice yourself instead of copy paste. Here is additional info for solution :

> In mathematics, the intersection A ∩ B of two sets A and B is the set
>   that contains all elements of A that also belong to B (or
>   equivalently, all elements of B that also belong to A), but no other
>   elements. For explanation of the symbols used in this article, refer
>   to the table of mathematical symbols.

In python :

> The syntax of intersection() in Python is:
>
> A.intersection(*other_sets)

```
A = {2, 3, 5, 4}
B = {2, 5, 100}
C = {2, 3, 8, 9, 10}

print(B.intersection(A))
print(B.intersection(C))
print(A.intersection(C))
print(C.intersection(A, B))
```

Comment: Thank you Paul! Really interesting solutions as well, but I am not that advanced yet. Will get there, but perhaps not today ;-)