# python how to use a for loop to print out vowels in a string

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I need to print out the vowels in horton in the order they appear using a for loop, this is what i have so far.

```
horton = "A person's a person, no matter how small."
vowels = "aeiouAEIOU" 
for letters in horton:
if letters == vowels[0:9]:
    print(letters)
```

Comment: Similar solutions to this question are also present here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46388214/find-and-print-vowels-from-a-string

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

Replace `if letters == vowels[0:9]:` to `if letters in vowels:` will solve your problem.

Simple explanation: `==` will check whether the left element is identical to the right element, in your case, to the left of `==` is a single letter, while to the right is "aeiouAEIO" (yeah, there's a capital U missing as well) and they can't be identical in any case.

Full programme:

```
horton = "A person's a person, no matter how small."
vowels = "aeiouAEIOU" 
for letters in horton:
    if letters in vowels:
        print(letters)
# A
# e
# o
# a
# e
# o
# o
# a
# e
# o
# a
```

Answer (score 0):

One-liner:

```
print(''.join([i for i in horton if i.lower() in 'aeiou']))
```

Output:

```
Aeoaeooaeoa
```

If want in newlines:

```
print('\n'.join([i for i in horton if i.lower() in 'aeiou']))
```

Output:

```
A
e
o
a
e
o
o
a
e
o
a
```

Or regex:

```
import re
print(''.join(re.findall(r'[aeiou]',"mississippi")))
```

Output:

```
Aeoaeooaeoa
```

If newline:

```
import re
print('\n'.join(re.findall(r'[aeiou]',"mississippi")))
```

Output:

```
A
e
o
a
e
o
o
a
e
o
a
```